# Optimise selection from a set, with constraints

Tags: r, optimization

I would like to use R to solve a problem I have.  I don't even know what to call a problem of this kind and I'm finding Googling difficult.  My guess is that this kind of problem already has R packages to help solve it, but I'd very much appreciate help defining the problem.

I want to select the optimum combination of agents, given some constraints.

I have a large set of agents, each of which has four 'measures':

1. **Category 1**:  can take 1 of 4 possible values
2. **Category 2**:  can take 1 of 20 possible values
3. **Cost**: a continuous variable
4. **Expected Return**:  a continuous variable

I wish to select a set of exactly 15 agents, to maximise **Expected Return**, with the following constraints:

1. There must be a certain number of agents from each value of **Category 1**
2. There is a maximum number of agents from each value of **Category 2**
3. There is a maximum **Cost**

What kind of problem is this, specifically?  Are you aware of any R packages that I could use / adapt to help me?  I specify R only as I am very comfortable with the language.

Many thanks for your time.

Comment: At first glance it sounds like a slightly more complicated version of a [*knapsack problem*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem). Your cost is 'weight' in the knapsack problem (using the terminology at the link at least), and your 'expected return' is 'value' in the knapsack problem. More specifically, you have a kind of [bounded knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_knapsack_problems#Direct_generalizations), but condition 1 adds additional constraints.

Answer (score 0):

This is some kind of [combinatorial optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_optimization) problem, and there is probably a specific name for it. There are a bunch of packages in the Optimization task view on the CRAN site, one of them might fit your needs.